# How to add tag(s) to all posts from a specific category?

Tags: posts, tags

I'm currently redesigning a cartoon site that has 1200+ posts, divided into about 62 different categories. Some categories have 2 posts in them, other categories have 50, 100, 200+.

Now for every category, I want to add a tag to all the posts in that category.

Does anybody know if there is a SQL query to automatically add a specific tag to all the posts in a category?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [Simple Tags](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-tags) which will allow you to bulk add tags on existing posts.

It might do the job you need